# Linker Command failed with exit code 1 Xcode 9

Tags: c++, xcode

So I've gone through a lot of these same questions and none of them seem to work for me.  I made a class that I use in my main called TokenClass.cpp.  The project will build fine as long as I don't have #include "TokenClass.cpp" in there(The only issue being I can't use that class anymore.)  I've tried deleting my DerivedData, and I this is my first project using xcode.

Comment: Never include a `.cpp` file. Add it to your project instead so that it is built as part of your project. With that said no one can give you specific help with only this amount of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not

#include "TokenClass.cpp"

You should include header files only (.h). Seems like you have infinite recursive includes.

Comment: Wow, yeah I haven't done coding in c++ for a while.  That was it haha.  Thanks